# How to show that $(1-ne^{-cn})^4\geq 1-c'e^{-c^{''}n}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

> Consider $(1-ne^{-cn})^4$, how to prove that there exist constants $c^{'}, c^{''}$ such that
>   $$(1-ne^{-cn})^4\geq 1-c'e^{-c^{''}n}$$

Note that the LHS= $(1-e^{-cn+\log n})^4$. But I am not sure how to do the next step.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yes. I do not think that expand the LHS by binomial is useful.

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I need this inequality to finish a proof.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik This is not a standard exercise in some textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Bernoulli's inequality:
$$
(1+x)^r \geq 1 + rx,\quad r\geq 1,\ x\geq -1.
$$
When $n$ is sufficiently large, it holds that $ne^{-cn}\leq 1$ and thus by Bernoulli's inequality,
$$
(1-ne^{-cn})^4\geq 1 - 4ne^{-cn} = 1-4e^{-cn+\log n}.
$$
Also, when $n$ is sufficiently large,
$$
e^{-cn+\log n} \leq e^{-c' n}
$$
for some $c' < c$. This shows that when $n$ is sufficiently large,
$$
(1-ne^{-cn})^4\geq  1 - 4e^{-c'n}.
$$
Now, to accommodate the finitely many smaller $n$, you can adjust the constant $4$ to another constant $c''$.